# How can I make “ls” show dotfiles first and preserve unicode filenames?

Tags: linux, unicode, ls

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .A
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 B
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .C
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 你好嗎
```

When I change `LC_ALL` to `C`, dot files are listed first, by unicode filenames are unreadable:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .A
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .C
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 B
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 ?????????
```

How can I make “ls” show dotfiles first and preserve unicode filenames?

UPDATE, solution found (thanks to Ярослав Рахматуллин's answer):

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
```

rebooted, show env:

```
$ env | grep -E 'LANG|LC'
LC_COLLATE=C
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

sorting as expected:

```
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi 4096 Jul 24 08:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .A
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 .C
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:33 B
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Jul 23 16:34 你好嗎
```

no warning from `perl -v`:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for arm-linux-gnueabihf-thread-multi-64int
(with 80 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2011, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Which terminal emulator and version of coreutils do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohho, your assumption seems incorrect. That is, I can list chinese files even without LC_ALL.

```
wraptor: ~/tmp/god-damn-mongorians
$ LC_ALL=C

$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 ??????????????????

$ unset LC_ALL

$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 我很好，谢谢

$ LANG=en_US.iso-8859-1

$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 ?▒???▒??好?▒??谢?谢
```

To acheive your goal you want to set LANG (or LANGUAGE) to a locale with a UTF encoding and set LC_COLLATE as our swedish friend suggested.

```
$ ll -a
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 0K 2013-07-23 12:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 ?▒???▒??好?▒??谢?谢

$ LANG=en_US.utf-8
$ LC_COLLATE=C    

$ ll -a
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 0K 2013-07-23 12:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 0K 2013-07-23 12:50 我很好，谢谢
```

---

*update:* 
Created three folders as per request in comment.

### Mintty

Launched as a native windows binary.

[image: mintty]

### URxvt

Launched from laptop, displayed under Xwin in Cygwin. Notice that the files are sorted "correctly" when LC_COLLATE is set.

[image: urxvt]

### Ubuntu virtual console in a VM

[image: VC]

Comment: please make 3 folders: `mkdir .A` `mkdir B` `mkdir .C`, besides showing unicode characters, I want to list dotfiles first.

Comment: @ohho Sure. Done.

Comment: 不客气 :) I'm so tired of encoding issues...

Answer (score 5):

The locale `C` does not do UTF-8. If you use a UTF-8-aware locale with the proper collation settings, then the `ls` invocation should behave as you expect. (You can build your own locale, if you find yourself doing this sort of thing often. For an example of a locale which brings in parts from other locales, you may want to look up [en_SE](http://www.stacken.kth.se/~auno/en_SE).)

If you only want to *sort* according to the C locale, you don't need to set LC_ALL (which is a [global override](http://teaching.idallen.com/net2003/06w/notes/character_sets.txt) for all other LC_* settings, hence the name) but can simply set [LC_COLLATE, which affects sorting](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/LC_COLLATE.htm) (the link is for AIX, but the overall description is general enough). In that case, `LC_COLLATE=C ls -al` should be close enough to what you want.

Comment: if I `unset LC_ALL`, unicode filenames will not be visiable. Which one of `LC_*` controls filename encoding?